# Get document on subarray containing date between aggregation mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Provided following collection:

```js
[
 { 
    events: [
     {
      triggers: [
       {
        date: "2019-12-12T23:00:00"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
 }
]
```

I want to be able to pull the documents that have any date in between a range of dates, let's say today and tomorrow.
Using following query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "events.triggers.date": {
        $gte: "2019-12-11T23:00:00.000Z",
        $lt: "2019-12-12T23:59:00.000Z"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

However, when I do this, the query seems to be looking at any document that has any date greater than and any date lower than but not necessarily in the same "trigger" object.

Anyone got any idea how you can filter in a subarray like this (I do more in my query afterwards so a find will not work) and have the date search be subitem specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found it eventually.

Those looking for the solution. Here it is:
`elemMatch`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "events.triggers": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "date": {
                $gte: "2019-12-11T23:00:00.000Z",
                $lt: "2019-12-12T23:59:00.000Z"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just some mistakes in your query. This should work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      '$and': [
        {"events.triggers.date": { '$gte': "2019-12-11T23:00:00.000Z" }},
        {"events.triggers.date": { '$lt': "2019-12-11T23:00:00.000Z" }}
      ]
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: This will render the same issue I have, with any document that has any date `gte` and any date `lt`. regardless of the index of the array.

Comment: Yh, I did not take note of that part of the question, my bad.